# Employer took bond and blank dated cheque. Is this legal in India?

Tags: employment, india, labor-law, employer

Suppose someone in India accepts a job with a software company, selected from on-campus placement.

The company did not disclose the agreement to be signed before the first day of employment, when they asked the employee to submit a blank dated cheque of INR 100,000 and a bond (on 100 INR stamp paper) which states that the employee would be under training of 6 months and thereafter would have to work for the next 18 months. But after joining, there was no training of any type and the employee simply worked as a proper employee. They didn't spend even a single penny for training.

They are kind of exploiting the employee to work on their live projects and it is really tough for the employee to handle it. After six months, the employee has decided to leave the company. The employee has talked to the CEO, and he is saying that they can take legal actions against the employee.

What can the company do regarding the bond and cheque? Can the employee be jailed if the cheque bounces? Or can the company file a complaint against the employee? What actions can the company take against the employee? And what can the employee do in his favor?

Comment: Because requests for individualized legal advice are off topic here, I've edited the question to make it impersonal and hypothetical.  You may learn something about your options here, but to get proper legal advice you should find a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for editing @phoog . I had no knowledge about the rules. Will remember for next time.

Comment: So what happend in the end?

Comment: I absconded from the company and cancelled the cheque as I had a good opportunity in hand so took the risk. Seems the employer wasn't educated enough OR he didn't want to spend time cashing out the cheque. If he would, it would be the charge against him as he used a cancelled cheque. It's one of the worst companies in India I would say which fakes even its glassdoor reviews :D